# SSAS/MDX averages over multiple time periods

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

How do I get averages for multiple time frames in the same result row in a SSAS/MDX query?

Requirements have changed and a report I wrote as a SSRS/SQL procedure based on a transactional DB has now moved to a data warehouse with SSAS cube. SSAS is new ground for me. I have spent several days trying to work my way through MDX after quickly realizing the drag and drop approach wasn't going to get me what I needed.

The scenario: logging performance time (specifically duration in milliseconds) of key pieces and processes of software in a large system. The idea of the report is to show worst performers based on historical precedence with an eye towards finding problematic areas when users say "the system is running slow".

The report columns:

- Function (actually several columns here but I'm sure I can get this working with them once I get one working)
- avg duration over last year
- avg duration over 1 week starting one year ago
- avg duration over last 6 months
- avg duration over 1 week starting 6 months ago
- avg duration over last month
- avg duration over 1 week starting one month ago
- avg duration over last week
- avg duration over last day
- avg duration selected day
- % decrease -> this is calculated in SSRS as the worst difference across all averages

The simplified cube - trying to follow recommendations from MS articles

- Activities.Duration MS
- Activities.Activities Count
- Functions.Fuction Key
- Functions.Function Desc
- Dates.Date Key (note that the Date dimension has no hierarchy at this point)
- Dates.Date Date

I got as far as the following and then started playing with the AVG() function and had little success.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Duration MS Avg] AS [Measures].[Duration Ms]/[Measures].[Activities Count]
SELECT
                     { [Measures].[Duration Ms], [Measures].[Activities Count], [Measures].[Duration MS Avg] } ON COLUMNS, 
                     { ([Functions].[Function Desc].[Function Desc].ALLMEMBERS )} ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( {[Dates].[Date Date].&[2016-05-24T00:00:00]} ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [DW]) 
WHERE ( [Dates].[Date Date].&[2016-05-24T00:00:00] )
```

Is this type of query even possible? Am I abusing SSAS?

Comment: You need a Hierarchy in your time dimension to achieve this more easly.More than one actually, one for Year->Month->Date and one for Year->Week->Date

Comment: So SSAS newbie question: In the MS whitepaper it described star vs snowflake and the snowflake showed 2 potential hierarchies of the Date dimension in the basis database (in their case actual date vs fiscal date). I also found somewhere that the Date dimension can just be marked as a Time dimension when creating the cube. Is one way better than the other? We have flexibility right now to get it right. Maybe a favourite reference link? I haven't found a really good one yet.

Comment: "Am I abusing SSAS?" - This cracked me up! :-D

Comment: I agree with @mxix's idea. Defining a proper date hierarchy is the way to go. After you do that, here's a very good article to get you started - http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-analysis-services/optimizing-time-based-calculations-ssas

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at this once I get some "lower priority" time.

Comment: What do you mean by "lower priority" time?

Comment: When all of the higher priorities have been addressed. Sometimes that it is a couple of days. Sometimes it is a couple of months :-) Sometimes the lower priority projects become burning priorities. Sometimes all of the higher priority projects are delayed waiting on other people.

Comment: I liked the article. Lots of good detail. His [follow up article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Analysis+Services+(SSAS)/65803/) should also be read.

Comment: Unfortunately some of my flexibility to get it right the first time has disappeared and will have to wait until the next project :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the time hierarchies it's harder to "travel" along the dates.

But here is a simple example for 2 of the measures you want as an example.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[Duration MS Avg] 
AS 
DIVIDE(
    [Measures].[Duration Ms]
    ,[Measures].[Activities Count]
)
MEMBER [Measures].[Duration MS Avg Over Last Day]
AS
DIVIDE(
    (
        [Dates].[Date Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1)
        ,[Measures].[Duration Ms]
    )
    ,(
        [Dates].[Date Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1)
        ,[Measures].[Activities Count]
    )
)
MEMBER [Measures].[Duration MS Avg Over Last Week]--Last 7 days
AS
DIVIDE(
    AGGREGATE(
        [Dates].[Date Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(7):[Dates].[Date Date].CURRENTMEMBER
        ,[Measures].[Duration Ms]
    )
    ,AGGREGATE(
        [Dates].[Date Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(7):[Dates].[Date Date].CURRENTMEMBER
        ,[Measures].[Activities Count]
    )
)
SELECT
{ 
    [Measures].[Duration Ms], 
    [Measures].[Activities Count], 
    [Measures].[Duration MS Avg],
    [Measures].[Duration MS Avg Over Last Week]
} ON COLUMNS, 
{ 
    (
        [Functions].[Function Desc].[Function Desc].ALLMEMBERS 
    )
} ON ROWS 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        ( {[Dates].[Date Date].&[2016-05-24T00:00:00]} ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [DW]
) 
WHERE 
    ( [Dates].[Date Date].&[2016-05-24T00:00:00] )
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. I get #Error for both new columns (I added the last day into the select as well). Would this happen if there was no data in the time period represented in the AGGREGATE set? These #Error results have been driving me crazy since I started looking at SSAS because I don't know what to do to debug them.

Comment: I am curious to know how this solution would work. `[Dates].[Date Date]` and `[Time].[Date]` are different hierarchies.

Comment: Could you try again SouravA spotted the issue ;) [Time].[Date] is a hierarchy in my test Cube.... missed the replace..

Comment: If you spotted it, please fix it too..it might be a bit confusing for the OP. BTW, there is another issue I feel. `[Dates].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER:[Dates].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(7)` should be changed to `[Dates].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(7):[Dates].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER`

Comment: Thx @SouravA. Fixed the incorrect Hierarchies. Still missed a couple after the first edit ... Changed the order of the Range "start" and "end" as advised, is more logically sound.

Comment: Thanks! Gave it a whirl and it ran. I added [Measures].[Duration MS Avg Over Last Day] into the select as well. I have voted up since it makes forward progress. I will come back and mark it as accepted once I have a few minutes to expand it for all the ranges and make sure I understand what it is doing! Might not be for a few days...pulled away to higher priorities :-)

Comment: One of the best features of SSAS is the ability to work Time Hierarchies with its built in functions. You should try and create a fully functional time dimension. After that all your calculation will be very straight foward. You can also do it with some data manipulation and VB code, but i do not advise it.

Comment: @mxix those `0`s will really hit performance - is there a reason they are not null?

Comment: I have tested the edited approach and have been able to make it do what I need. Due to time constraints I will leave implementing date hierarchies until the next project :-) Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No problem, once you have those hiearchies setup, ask the question again ,) you will get much more interesting answers for sure! You can do really cool thing in MDX with hierarchies.

Comment: @mxix `mdx` tag has been proposed for documentation - can you add your vote please as we need several votes to create the documentation for this tag: stackoverflow.com/documentation/mdx